On partitioning an arbitrary union of sets
I am looking for a general formula to decompose an arbitrary union of $n$ sets into disjoint sets. For example, consider the arbitrary union of two sets $A,B$. Then it can be written as $A\cup B=(A\setminus (A\cap B))\cup (A\cap B)\cup (B\setminus (A\cap B))$, where $(A\setminus (A\cap B))$, $(A\cap B)$, and $(B\setminus (A\cap B))$ are disjoint. For a union of three sets, the decomposition is already much more complicated, so much so that I will not write it down here. Is there a general formula to decompose an arbitrary union of $n$ sets into disjoint sets? (I am sure somebody figured it out!)

Consider writing $A \setminus B$ instead of $A\setminus (A\cap B)$ for simpler notation, as they indicate the same set

Without further requirements, you can write any set $X$ as the disjoint union of ${X}$. But going with the spirit of your example, you could partition $\bigcup_i A_i$ into $2^n-1$ subsets, one for each "region" of the Venn diagram formed by the $A_i$.

@NaïmFavier I think you should post your comment as an answer. The components correspond to the $2^n$ bit vectors that indicate which sets are "in" or "out:.

Let $\{ A_i \}_{i=1}^n$ be a family of $n$ sets.
For a subset $S \subset \{ 1,2,\ldots,n \}$, denote $S^c = \{ 1,2,\ldots,n \} \setminus S$ and $A^S := \bigcup\limits_{i \in S} A_i$.
We can write $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n A_k$ as the union of disjoint sets as
$$ \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n A_k = \bigcup\limits_{S} \left[ \left( \bigcap\limits_{i \in S} A_i \right) \setminus \left( \bigcup\limits_{j \in S^c} A_j \right) \right] . $$

Sorry, I don't get it. Could you please give an example for n=2? Or, even better, n=3?

For $n=3$, there are terms of the kind $A \setminus (B \cup C)$, and of the kind $(A \cap B) \setminus C$, and lastly $A \cap B \cap C$. The expression written above will give you in total $A \cup B \cup C = \left( A \setminus (B \cup C) \right) \cup \left( B \setminus (A \cup C) \right) \cup \left( C \setminus (A \cup B) \right) \cup \left( (A \cap B) \setminus C \right) \cup \left( (A \cap C) \setminus B \right) \cup \left( (B \cap C) \setminus A \right) \cup \left( A \cap B \cap C \right)$.

Thank you for the clarification.
